# В чем различие между ReadLine() и ReadExisting() у COM-Port'а

Tags: c#, com-port

Необходимо считывать данные с COM-порта. Обычно рекомендуют пользоваться методом ReadLine(). Однако на моем устройстве этот метод часто возвращает пустую строку. Пробовал использовать ReadExisting() в сочетании с Thread.Sleep() почти 100 % положительный результат.

```
Thread.Sleep(100);
var response = comPort.ReadExisting();
```

Вот и вопрос: а где подвох? Почему везде и в Инете, и в литературе, и MSDN в том числе, рекомендуют использовать ReadLine()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadExisting получает все данные их буфера. ReadLine ожидает значения окончания строки, затем возвращает строку. Если были получены данные, но не было значения окончания строки, ReadLine ничего не вернет. Поэтому, если вы работаете с текстом, используйте ReadLine. Если работаете с нетекстовой информацией, используйте ReadExisting.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Что значит работать с текстовой информацией? У меня устройство для дозирования жидкостей. При работе я посылаю через COM-Port соответствующие команды и мне нужно получить результат. Это, к примеру, может быть статус устройства или вес емкости с жидкостью и т.д. Эти данные, я конечно же, получаю в виде текстовой строки от устройства.

Comment: Вы получаете строки, они как-то разделяются. Например, через `\n`. Тогда сделайте так `serialPort.NewLine="\n";` и все должно работать через ReadLine(). Второй вариант это считывать через ReadExisting() и разбивать на строки самому. Если вы работаете в режиме один вопрос - один ответ, и ответ не заканчивается на символ новой строки, тогда, думаю, ReadExisting() в преимуществе.

Comment: Теперь понятнее. Обычно все мои команды заканчиваются на "\n\r\n", но ответы, как правило получаю в виде одной строки. В общем, направление понятно, буду пробовать. Спасибо за помощь!